# xdotool - how to get window id given its X and Y?

Tags: xdotool

I can get X and Y of the active window with `xdotool getwindowgeometry --shell $(xdotool getactivewindow)`. How do I do a backwards process - find window id given its X and Y? I'm only interested in the topmost window, not the one that may be hidden underneath the one on top.

Comment: Do you want the id of the active window or of the one at a particular position irrespective of whether it is active?

Comment: @terdon, second - otherwise I'd just use `getactivewindow`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've figured it out myself:

`xdotool mousemove 500 100 getmouselocation --shell mousemove restore`

This briefly moves the mouse to the specified position (x=500, y=100 in this example), prints `WINDOW` which is the `windowid` on top, then moves the mouse back.

This is probably not the intended usage of mousemove, but I could not find any better way to do what I wanted.