# How do I find out the window name of fullscreen internet content (eg Flash)?

Tags: x11, monitoring, openbox, window

--- The context ---

I'm using Openbox to create a dedicated workspace/desktop for my browser -- the browser only opens on that workspace, and any other windows created on it get kicked onto a different workspace.

This works for most of my browsing, but with fullscreen-capable content such as streaming videos or Flash apps, switching to 'fullscreen mode' actually creates a new window for the content to play in... so Openbox kicks it off the dedicated workspace. Meaning, when I exit fullscreen mode I'm on my random clutter workspace instead of back in my browser.

I need to write an exception so Openbox lets the fullscreen content stay on the dedicated workspace.

--- The problem ---

I would like to use `xprop` (or just `wmctrl -l`) to get some info on the window that the fullscreen web content plays in, but the window automatically closes as soon as it loses focus (as far as I can tell) so I can't just switch to my terminal and do it manually. I need some way to log the info in the background. Ideally I'd like some kind of background monitor that logs the name of every window that gets opened.

Is there a relatively simple way to script this? I'm sure I could find a monitoring software package that could do this, but it seems like overkill for what I need.

EDIT to add answer:
Just using a timer (`sleep 10; xprop`) as suggested by Gilles worked. For  future reference the relevant line was `_OB_APP_CLASS(UTF8_STRING) = "Plugin-container"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A program that monitors window creation doesn't come to mind, but you don't need that.

You can run `wmctrl -l` in a loop or on a timer (e.g. `sleep 10; wmctrl -l`) and then start the fullscreen application and record its window properties. If you want more information, you can do something like

```
sleep 10; xprop
```

After 10 seconds, the mouse cursor will change; clicking should make `xprop` display information about the foreground window.

Alternatively, use `xdotool` (again on a timer or in a loop) and its window matching capabilities to find the window ID, e.g. `xdotool --pid` if the full-screen window is in a pre-existing process, or `xdotool getwindowfocus` or `getactivewindow` to get the window ID of the window that has the focus. Note that the foreground window may in fact not have the input focus (some full-screen applications display an additional full-screen window in the foreground but keep the focus in their “normal” window; you can [query the window at some screen location instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179743/xdotool-how-to-get-window-id-given-its-x-and-y), or simply `xdotool getmouselocation` for a full-screen window (for a multi-monitor setup, if the mouse cursor is already on the right monitor).

Alternatively, on Linux, switch to a text console (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), log in, run `export DISPLAY=:0`, and then you can access the GUI (run `xprop`, `xdotool`, etc.). With some setups [you may need to set `XAUTHORITY` as well](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display).